# Calculate $[E: \mathbb{Q}]$ and show that $E$ is a Galois extension on $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, galois-extensions

> **Problem:** Let $f(x) = x^5 - 2x^4 - 2x^3 + 4x^2 - 3x + 6 \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$. Let $E$ be the spliting field of $f(x)$. Calculate $[E: \mathbb{Q}]$ and show that $E$ is a Galois extension on $\mathbb{Q}$.

**My attempt:** We have $f(x) = (x-2)(x^2 - 3)(x^2 + 1)$. Roots of $f(x)$ are $2, \sqrt{3}, - \sqrt{3}, i, -i$. So $E = \mathbb{Q} (1, \sqrt{3}, -\sqrt{3}, i, -i) = \mathbb{Q} (\sqrt{3}, -\sqrt{3}, i, -i) = \mathbb{Q} (\sqrt{3},i)$, implies $[E: \mathbb{Q}] = 4$.

How to show that $E$ be a Galois extension?

Comment: It is a splitting field.

Comment: @ÍgjøgnumMeg Could you explain more?

Comment: Separability of the extension is automatic because $E$ has characteristic $0$. The extension is normal because for any $\sigma : E \hookrightarrow \overline{\Bbb Q}$ such that $\sigma|_{\Bbb Q} = \operatorname{id}$ you get $\sigma(E) = E$ (and that's just because all the $\sigma$ do is conjugate $\sqrt{3}$ and $i$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done almost everything you need. You only need to find the useful results to apply them and conclude what you want.

Let me recall what a Galois Extension is.

> **Definition 1.** Let $K\subseteq F$ be an extension. Then, $K\subseteq F$ is a Galois extension if it is normal and separable.
>
> **Definition 2.** Let $K\subseteq F$ be an extension. Then, $K\subseteq F$ is a normal extension if
>
> i) $K\subseteq F$ is algebraic;
>
> ii) if $p(x)\in K[x]$ is irreducible and contains one of its roots in $F$, it implies that all its roots are in $F$.
>
> **Definition 3.** Let $K\subseteq F$ be an extension. Then, $K\subseteq F$ is separable if all $\alpha \in F$ is separable, i.e. $\alpha \in F$ is algebraic and its irreducible polynomial does not contain repeated roots in its splitting field.

Let me recall also 2 distinct results which will be useful.

> **Theorem 1.** If $[F:K]<\infty$, then $K\subseteq F$ is normal if and only if $F$ is the splitting field of some $p(x)\in K[x]\setminus K$.
>
> **Proposition 1.** If $ch(K)=0$, then $K\subseteq F$ is separable if and only if $K\subseteq F$ is algebraic.

Now, since we are in $K=\mathbb{Q}$ and $E=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},i)$, we have that $\mathbb{Q}\subseteq\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},i)$ is finite and hence it is algebraic. Thus, since $ch(\mathbb{Q})=0$, it is separable. Moreover, since $E$ is the splitting field of $p(x)$, which is not a constant polynomial, $E$ is also normal.

Then, we can conclude that $\mathbb{Q}\subseteq\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},i)$ is normal and separable, i.e. it is a Galois extension.